# How to control the width and height of input field of a standard field?

Tags: visualforce

How to control the width and height of input field of a standard field? As of now I am controlling the width by using

```
style="width:500px"
```

But how to set the height?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an textarea instead of input, you ca only manipulate the width of an input.

Answer (score 0):

The same way, just use

```
style="width:500px; height:100px;"
```

You can also play with "font-size", "border" and "padding" to make it look good.

Here are some examples of it http://cssbutton.com/forms/
Stuff marked as CSS can be used in style="" tag, just as you did with width.